# How did Lucius Fox revive the failing Wayne Enterprise?

Tags: dc, batman

In Batman Comics and some other adaptations, Lucius Fox is called in to revive the failing [Wayne Enterprises](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Wayne_Enterprises). How exactly did Lucius Fox revive Wayne Enterprise? 
What are his qualifications? Does he have a past history of reviving failed companies?

For example, did he sell off the company's unprofitable units? Did he acquire profitable companies etc, etc.

I find it somewhat strange that most Batman Comics that I have read,have never defined the business management skills of Fox despite the fact that Fox has been described as a brilliant mind time and again.

Comment: Well, in the Nolan trilogy Lucius Fox is God, so...

Answer (score 5):

Quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucius_Fox#Business_career):

> Lucius Fox is regarded as having the "Midas Touch", **an ability to turn failing businesses into successful conglomerates**, and is consequently a highly sought-after businessman throughout the corporate world. Fox is called in to the failing Wayne Enterprises and brings a balance to both Bruce Wayne's private and business finances. (The DC Comics Encyclopedia) In *Batman Confidential*, he is shown heading the project that produced the prototype that would become the Batwing. He also manages the particulars of the Wayne Foundation while Bruce dictates the organization's general policies. Since then, Fox has been approached time and time again by other companies seeking his expertise. After overcoming the original challenge of returning Wayne Enterprises to its former glory, Fox has elected to stay, having been given an unparalleled freedom in the company.

So it sounds like he's simply really good at what he does. The entry goes on to say that "a young Bruce Wayne rescued Lucius Fox from muggers in Paris" which partially explains why he started working for Wayne Enterprises.

As for details, I don't think they've ever been explained. Presumably, it's just like such people in the real world. He has a knack for crunching the data to find what is profitable, what is not, and who can be trusted.

Comment: Thanks! I actually went through that Wikipedia entry before I posted the question.Just like you said, I too realized that `the entry does not mention how he helped spark a turnaround at Wayne Enterprises`. I checked several of my DC comics as well. The details are not provided there either. Thanks again.